# Do jagged contours indicate more spatial variability in a data set?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, contour

A general question when working with contours, do jagged lines indicate more spatial variability in a data set?

A short background of my problem and objective: I would like to delineate neighborhoods based on historical home prices to create homogenous markets for actively listed homes. I have used the GA extension and chosen the covariance variable and circular model. My data set contains nearly 600 points and returned a regression function of 0.81 with a mean prediction of 1137 or so for home price. I am exporting my filled contour prediction map to GA Contours.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spatial variance"?  This is an uncommon term without a standard definition AFAIK. (Ecologists seem to use it vaguely to mean spatial *variability*.) If there is to be any relationship to "jagged lines," then--because "jagged" is a *local* property--it sounds like you are thinking of some local measure of variability, such as the nugget of a variogram or perhaps a neighborhood standard deviation or neighborhood range. Also, because the appearance of contour lines depends on the algorithm used to construct them, please tell us how you are constructing your lines.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  A short background of my problem and objective:  I would like to delineate neighborhoods based on historical home prices to create homogenous markets for actively listed homes.  I have used the GA extension and chosen the covariance variable and circular model.  My data set contains nearly 600 points and returned a regression function of 0.81 with a mean prediction of 1137 or so for home price.  I am exporting my filled contour prediction map to GA Contours.

Comment: Would you be able to use the additional information you provided as a comment to revise your question so that it can stand alone?  I suspect that the inclusion of a diagram or two may help potential answerers.

Answer (score 2):

A common cause for this is using the wrong resample method when translating your DEM to a different coordinate system.  `Nearest Neighbor` will produce the effect you describe.  `Cubic` is a better option for continuous data.